# Template Specialization for Private Types

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, friend

I have a generic algorithm that needs to access its template type's traits. There is a trait class that can be specialized for providing these traits.

When using this algorithm within my class, I'd like to use it with a private type defined within the class.

However, specialization can only happen within `namespace` or global scope where my class is inaccessible.

```
class A
{
    struct Secret 
    {};
};

template <typename T> struct Trait {};

// Inaccessible type ----vvvvvvvvv
template <> struct Trait<A::Secret> // Specialize for  PRIVATE type A::Secret
{ 
    A::Secret magic_value() { return{}; } // ERROR: 'A::Secret': cannot access private struct declared in class 'A'
};
```

Is it possible to somehow specialize a template with a private type, at least in scopes where this type is accessible?

Maybe it's possible to declare the specialization a `friend` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make class template `Trait` the friend of class `A` via [template friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends).

```
template <typename T> struct Trait {};
class A
{
    struct Secret 
    {};

    template <typename T>
    friend struct Trait;
};
```

Or refer to the full specialization of `A::Secret`.

```
template <typename T> struct Trait {};
class A
{
    struct Secret 
    {};

    friend struct Trait<A::Secret>;
};
```

Comment: Bingo! Just what I needed :-). Thanks.

Comment: @AdiShavit You should accept this answer if it solved your problem.